# Sorting a concatenated pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, concatenation

I want to concatenate two pandas dataframes `A` and `B` und afterwards sort them by two columns `'geohash'` and `'timestamp'`

```
A
    geohash  timestamp
0   a2a      15
1   b3a      14

B
    geohash  timestamp
0   a2b      15
1   b3b      14
```

After

```
AB = pd.concat([A,B],ignore_index=True)
AB.sort_values(['geohash','timestamp'])
```

I expect

```
AB
    geohash  timestamp
0   a2a      15
1   a2b      15
2   b3a      14
3   b3b      14
```

But I get

```
AB
    geohash  timestamp
0   a2a      15
1   b3a      14
2   a2b      14
3   b3b      15
```

Why does'nt pandas sort the whole dataframe `AB`?

Comment: This is my first question, I'm open for hints on how to improve it :)

Comment: Your output seems to be a little off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort_values` does not happen in place. So when you run:

```
AB.sort_values(['geohash','timestamp'])
```

It is not updating `AB` rather returning a copy

```
AB.sort_values(['geohash','timestamp'], inplace=True)
```

Will update `AB`

Alternatively you can assign the sorted dataframe to a new variable

```
AB_sorted = AB.sort_values(['geohash','timestamp'])
AB_sorted 

geohash timestamp
0   a2a 15
2   a2b 15
1   b3a 14
3   b3b 15
```

Comment: after sorting, i want  to make the indexes in sequence order. How can i do it?

Comment: @AkhilMittal
You can try df.reset_index()
see [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)